# Java: Reference to a key value in JSON

Tags: java, json, pointers

I am creating a json file where I want to store chat's messages. There is a chat key with an id value, users' ids array and a messages key with an object array where I want to store the message id, the author id and the content for every message in the chat. But instead of always writing the author id over and over again for every message is there a way to reference to the users' ids values I wrote before? In this way I only have to write once.

```
{
  "chat": {
    "id": "0001",
    "users": ["1234", "4567"],
    "messages": [
      {"msg_id": "0", "author": "1234","content": "How are you?"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Any specific language you're looking for? i.e. Python, etc.?

Comment: I'm going to parse the file in java

Comment: Identifier are already reference. I don't understand your problem? If anything, that's the `users` array that is duplicate as it may be found in `messages` using author key. Otherwise, if you really want to reference something in `users`, why not referencing in `authors` the index in `users`? (I would not do that personally).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a good way to avoid specifying the author ID with each message, especially if the messages are ordered in some way, possibly by time. If the messages were unordered, then you could potentially group by author:

```
authors: [
  {
     id: 1234,
     messages: [ { ... }, ... ]
  },
  ...
]
```

But I don't think that's what you want.

I think the way that most designers would do this would be to include, in the `users` section, a lot of information about each user (ID, name, avatar URL, reputation, etc.), then just use the user ID to identify the author of each message. Your example is unusual in that you *only* include the user ID in the `users` section.